Terraform deploy issue
currently I'm working on DevOps Deployment Automation with Terraform, AWS and Docker
project from Udemy, and I've stuck with this error on GitHub Actions, it does not deploy TF file on s3 buckethere is screnshot of an eror
ps I use credentials from: terraform output command, checked my iam.tf file and variables.tf everything seems correct
Help me please
Ive tried GPT, changed commands on my *.tf files used different credentials, reloging to my aws sso cli, checked policies on aws
HERE IS OUTPUT FROM GITHUB ACTIONS

operation error DynamoDB: PutItem, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: 0NTHCFGF856DKB38SVBASDQQKVVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG, api error AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:iam::891376961380:user/recipe-app-api-cd is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:PutItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:891376961380:table/devops-recipe-app-api-terraform-lock because no identity-based policy allows the dynamodb:PutItem action

Unable to retrieve item from DynamoDB table "devops-recipe-app-api-terraform-lock": operation error DynamoDB: GetItem, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: 7I0K14A5GSCKNDA99PARPF3F63VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG, api error AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:iam::891376961380:user/recipe-app-api-cd is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:GetItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:891376961380:table/devops-recipe-app-api-terraform-lock because no identity-based policy allows the dynamodb:GetItem action




how did you create this user IAM recipe-app-api-cd   ? did you create from TF or you directly created in the console? answer this and i can help you with the solution

Your iam user that is running terraform will need permissions to read and write to dynamodb to allow state locking.

Hello @0xn0b174 IAM user was created from TF

@Chris Doyle permissions seems to be correct, it pushes to ecr but TF isn't deploying , so I'm confused they should be working under the same user credentials

The error is very clear. The user recipe-app-api-cd does not have permissions for dynamo. Regardless if you say the permissions seem correct. Clearly aws Iam is telling you it doesnt

updated IAM policy attached to user recipe-app-api-cd similar to this directly in IAM or in you terraform :
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "dynamodb:PutItem",
        "dynamodb:GetItem",
        "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
        "dynamodb:DeleteItem"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:891376961380:table/devops-recipe-app-api-terraform-lock"
    }
  ]
}


make sure the resource ARN matches your DynamoDB table
and your terrafomr backend configuration should be similar to this:
  backend "s3" {
    bucket         = "your-s3-bucket-name"
    key            = "path/to/terraform.tfstate"
    region         = "us-east-1"
    dynamodb_table = "devops-recipe-app-api-terraform-lock"  # Ensure this is correct
  }
}


if you can confirm this and run your github actions pipeline.
you can adjust policy wherever you want and easy for you.
